# python ImportError using PyAL with kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy, openal

To be able to use 3D sound, I am trying to use the OpenAl sound library (PyAL) in kivy. Here's the python header of the main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.2')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

from openal.loaders import load_wav_file
from openal.audio import SoundSink, SoundSource, SoundData, SoundListener
[...]
```

OpenAl is not included in the standard options provided by kivys python for android, so I created a `pyal/recipe.sh` for it.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                
# version of your package                                                       
VERSION_pyal=${VERSION_pyal:-0.1.0}                                             

# dependencies of this recipe                                                   
DEPS_pyal=()                                                                    

# url of the package                                                            
URL_pyal=https://bitbucket.org/marcusva/py-al/downloads/PyAL-0.1.0.tar.gz       

# md5 of the package                                                            
MD5_pyal=862a9345004c76651dcf91b7d990fe84                                       

# default build path                                                            
BUILD_pyal=$BUILD_PATH/pyal/$(get_directory $URL_pyal)                          

# default recipe path                                                           
RECIPE_pyal=$RECIPES_PATH/pyal                                                  

# function called for preparing source code if needed                           
# (you can apply patch etc here.)                                               
function prebuild_pyal() {                                                      
  true                                                                          
}                                                                               

# function called to build the source code                                      
function build_pyal() {                                                         
  true                                                                          
}                                                                               

# function called after all the compile have been done                          
function postbuild_pyal() {                                                     
  true                                                                          
}
```

Compiling the toolchain works:

```
Download package for pyal
[...]
Call prebuild_pyal
[...]
Call build_pyal
[...]
Call postbuild_pyal
[...]
All done !
```

Building the apk works, and so does installing. But when running the app on the device (Nexus 4), it closes immediately. Netcat complains:

```
[...]
I/python  (13175):  ImportError: No module named openal.loaders
I/python  (13175): Python for android ended.
[...]
```

Somehow the inclusion of PyAL in the toolchain went wrong. Any ideas what the problem could be?

On my Laptop (Ubuntu 14.04), everything works fine. Not a huge surprise, since it should use the python from the repository, not kivys python for android.

Comment: should you not need to be using setup.py install in your build_pyal?

Answer (score 1):

Your python-for-android recipe is for PyAL (Python bindings for OpenAL), but PyAL requires that OpenAL be installed to do anything. You probably don't need a recipe for PyAL - which appears to be a pure Python module - but you will have to create a recipe for OpenAL. Creating that recipe will require knowing how to build OpenAL, so you may need help from their maintainers.

Comment: brousch, what is the openal  in the PyAL-0.1.0.tar.gz file?

Comment: Those are the Python wrappers for OpenAL. OpenAL itself is not included in PyAL. Quickly browsing the OpenAL page, it looks like they have Android support, so it should be possible to use with python-for-android, but walking through that process is beyond my available time right now.